# Integrating Tapku Library to XCode 4.6 project

Tags: ios6, xcode4.6, tapku

Its been a long since I am struggling integrating the Tapku Library in my Xcode project. I want to implement the Day View component from Tapku into my project. I followed the instructions from read-me on github but had no success. I am getting following error, "**Apple Compiler LLVM Error**" when I add the files to my project. Anyone who has successfully integrated the same please help.

Comment: If you found a solution please share.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue by using Finder (before opening xCode) copy the `src` folder to my projects directory.

So my project structure is `MyProject/Frameworks/src`

For the rest of the steps just follow the guide on Tapku's GitHub page.

- Only add the 2 TapkuLibrary.xcodeproj and src/TapkuLibrary.bundle files
- Select the Build Phases
- Link Binary With Libraries
- For the Header Search Path you can use `$(SRCROOT)/Frameworks/src`  remember to use non-recursive option
- And for Other Linker Flags add `-ObjC`

Hope this helps